# Импорт XML файла в базу данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой XML файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

<Товары>

    <Товар Код="201" Название="Бумага А4">

        <Цена Тип="Базовая">11.50</Цена>

        <Цена Тип="Москва">12.50</Цена>

        <Свойства>

            <Плотность>100</Плотность>

            <Белизна ЕдИзм="%">150</Белизна>

        </Свойства>

        <Разделы>

            <Раздел>Бумага</Раздел>

        </Разделы>

    </Товар>

    <Товар Код="202" Название="Бумага А3">

        <Цена Тип="Базовая">18.50</Цена>

        <Цена Тип="Москва">22.50</Цена>

        <Свойства>

            <Плотность>90</Плотность>

            <Белизна ЕдИзм="%">100</Белизна>

        </Свойства>

        <Разделы>

            <Раздел>Бумага</Раздел>

        </Разделы>

    </Товар>

    <Товар Код="302" Название="Принтер Canon">

        <Цена Тип="Базовая">3010</Цена>

        <Цена Тип="Москва">3500</Цена>

        <Свойства>

            <Формат>A4</Формат>

            <Формат>A3</Формат>

            <Тип>Лазерный</Тип>

        </Свойства>

        <Разделы>

            <Раздел>Принтеры</Раздел>

            <Раздел>МФУ</Раздел>

        </Разделы>

    </Товар>

    <Товар Код="305" Название="Принтер HP">

        <Цена Тип="Базовая">3310</Цена>

        <Цена Тип="Москва">2999</Цена>

        <Свойства>

            <Формат>A3</Формат>

            <Тип>Лазерный</Тип>

        </Свойства>

        <Разделы>

            <Раздел>Принтеры</Раздел>

            <Раздел>МФУ</Раздел>

        </Разделы>

    </Товар>

</Товары>
```

мне нужно написать функцию которая импортирует его в БД, ее я уже создал на локальном сервере, таблицы связал, древовидную структуру для категорий реализовал.
Подскажите в каком направление мне нужно двигаться для реализации этой функции, желательно пошагово. Я с json файлами немного разобрался с XML первый раз столкнулся. По  возможности порекомендуйте статью или видео где что то подобное разбирается.

Comment: все достаточно просто https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php

Comment: я так понял лучше xml конвертировать в json и работать с ним, я не очень понимаю один момент  у меня теги на русском а поля таблицы на английском, как парсить xml

Comment: в json вы мне кажется потеряете атрибуты - код товара и тп. что касается имен -  сдклайте массив перекодировки - имя в xml => имя в базе и пройдите циклом, например